# how to transform the position of an object

Tags: unity, monodevelop

I am trying to transform the position of an object. I have totally 3 Objects and 2 triggers, objects are 1. Left_Wall, 2. Right_Wall, 3. Obstacles. 1st trigger for transform the position of an objects y = -50, 2nd trigger for transform the position of an objects y = -7. Left wall and Right Wall are placed inside the environment. the environment will instantiate automatically for looping. if the player crossed the first environment previous environment will delete automatically. at that time in second clone environment if the player triggered means it will display a message as

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>   Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

In first Clone environment its working perfectly. second clone environment its not working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please please please use *Code Blocks* to paste your code instead of screenshots.

Now you say that

> the environment will instantiate automatically for looping

And your variables *sideLft* and *sideRit* are null when you need them. So why not perform the search of the scene just before you do your action? Take your code from *Start* function and move it in the beginning your *OnTriggerEnter*. I would provide a code block for you if I could copy some from your question.

Comment: yes, I  also did the same. now the problem is i want to change and reset only y position . if i gives **sideLft.transform.position = new vectro3 (0,-50,0);** Means the game object x position is moving to 0.

Comment: then you can do:

`Vector3 pos = sideLft.transform.position;
pos.y = -50f;
sideLft.transform.position = pos;`